# .htaccess mvc rewrite

Tags: php

trying to rewrite index.php?controller=post&id=1 to /post/1 without "index.php", i've got it working WITH index.php in the url with:

```
RewriteRule ^(post)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?controller=post&action=show&id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And I don't understand why it's not working with just example.com/post/1 but it is with example.com/index.php/post/1 any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what's the problem? It shows the respective profiles as well as you.

Comment: But it doesn't. I navigate to mywebsite.com/profile.php?id=5 which is a random profile I setup to test it and it shows my profile still.

Comment: When your session is set?

Comment: If I am logged in on my account "id=2" and I try to navigate to the other users account "id=5" it just shows me my account.

Comment: I think your session['user'] is set when you logged in. If it is true then from your code you always make a query where user_id is always your session value.

Comment: Do you know a solution so I can view my own profile and other users profiles by changing the id in the url?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `<a>` tag for every person's profile with a href like
 `<a href="profile.php?id=3">Person 3</a>
<a href="profile.php?id=4">Person 4</a>`
....

Your profile.php should like this-

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id='$id';
$que = mysql_query($sql);
$useRow = mysql_fetch_array($que);
?>
```

Set the `<a>` dynamically when you set them at your webpage.